# Select elements under different conditions in a single postgreSQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and I was wondering if it is possible to select from table columns using different conditions for each column in a single query.  For instance: say I have a table with three columns called 'name' 'birthday' and 'salary.' I want to select from name when either birthday or salary are empty, but I only want to select from birthday and salary if they themselves are empty (ie. if a row has a name, no birthday, and a salary, only name and birthday would be selected). Is there a way to do this in postgreSQL?

Comment: Can you illustrate your question with sample data?

Comment: @Macklin . . . The columns chosen in a SQL query are fixed, so you cannot return variable columns.  What happens in your case is that some columns might be `NULL` -- and the application layer might need to figure out what to do with them.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Please edit your question to provide sample data, sample criteria and sample query output so we can understand what you want. Right now, it is unlikely you will get any answers.

Answer (score 0):

The columns in the SQL query in PostgreSQL are fixed (unlike Informix where you can have variable-column result sets).  There are. however a few ways around this.

1. Use JSON and a monster CASE statement.
2. Use HSTORE and a monster CASE statement
3. Use JSON and a function to assemble the information flexibly.
4. Use HSTORE and a function to assemble the information flexibly.

My recommendation is that if you really want this, JSON with function would be the best way forward if you are on at least 9.1 (and can install extensions) or 9.2 (even without extensions).  This is not extremely easy to do, and it takes some practice but it is possible.

The other option is to return NULL where the value is not found and handle that on the client-side.